# Code sharing when using composition

Tags: swift, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, composition

Let's say we have the following class (simplified):

```
class AudioRecorder {
    private func onRecord(data: [Float]) {
        self.delegate?.audioRecorder(self, didRecordFrame: audioData)

    public func record() { ... }
    public func stop() { ... }
}
```

So it records frame and notifies it's delegate about it.
Now I need to extend it with the following capabilities:

1. Buffering - Buffer X number of frames
2. Interval recording - Record - stop 1s - Record - stop 1s ...
3. Interval buffering - record in intervals and buffer

I can't use inheritance for this because if `IntervalRecorder` and `BufferingRecorder` are subclasses then I have problem implementing `IntervalBufferingRecorder`.

On another hand, when using composition solution could look something like this:

```
class BufferingRecorder {
  private let recorder: AudioRecorder

  func audioRecorder(recorder: AudioRecorder, didRecordFrame: [Float]) {
      // buffering logic
  }

  // need to duplicate play and stop
  func record() {
    self.recorder.startRecording()
  }

  func stop() {
    self.recorder.stop()
  }
}
```

I need to duplicate play pause methods in all of `IntervalRecorder`, `BufferingRecorder` and `IntervalBufferingRecorder` and just forward to underlying object.

What would be good approach to this problem? Language is Swift but I guess that is not very important.

Comment: There is a famous WWDC video on protocol oriented programming and here is another tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/148448/introducing-protocol-oriented-programming. Go through it and you will get the idea.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague for me, it could be better if you can try to explain a bit more about your classes and subclasses. If you want to avoid inheritance, try to use a protocol with default implementation.

Comment: `play` and `stop` are not record functions, and this violates the principle of interface segregation (right?). I would separate the `Recorder` behavior in its own class and use the `Decorator` pattern. An `AudioWidget` would have default `play` and `stop` methods that work on its `recorder` instance that you can configure at will.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is `record` and `stop`. I will update my question.

Answer (score 1):

This might give you an idea on how to use protocols with default implementation.

```
protocol Bufferable {
    func buffer(data: [Float])
}

extension Bufferable {
    func buffer(data: [Float]) {
        print("buffering")
    }
}

protocol Recordable {
    func record(data: [Float])
}

extension Recordable {
    func record(data: [Float]) {
        print("recording")
    }
}

class AudioPlayer: Bufferable, Recordable {

    func start() {
        buffer(data: [2.0, 1.0, 1.0])
        record(data: [2.0, 1.0, 1.0])
    }

}

class VideoPlayer: Bufferable, Recordable {

    func start() {
        buffer(data: [2.0, 1.0, 1.0])
        record(data: [2.0, 1.0, 1.0])
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think this doesn't answer my question. I don't want pollute AudioRecorder with anything else then recording.